# Can't search items with ' in title

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, online

I have a simple generic list with no customization (only the title column is present).

I put some values in the list, including one as `It's working`.

When I search this value, I get no result. I'm convinced this is due to the single quote `'`in the title.

Here's searches I tried, and their results :

- `"it's working"` ==> no result
- `"it's*"` ==> no result
- `it's*` ==> **result found**
- `it's working` ==> no result
- `"it*"` ==> **result found**
- `Title:"it's working"` ==> no result
- `Title:"it's*"` ==> no result
- `Title:it's*` ==> no result
- `Title:"it*"` ==> **result found**
- `Title:"it''s working"` ==> no result
- `Title:"it\'s working"` ==> no result
- `Title:"it%27's working"` ==> no result
- `Title:"it`'s working"` ==> no result
- `Title="it's working"` ==> no result
- `Title:string("it's working")` ==> no result

I don't understand these results. Quotes seems to cause trouble in finding the value, but quotes are required to search for the whole value.

My context is a modern sharepoint search page.

I also noticed the same behavior using the search query tool. When I put the candidate search string in the tool, it fail with an error 400:

`/_api/search/query?querytext='"it's+working"'&rowlimit=50&clienttype='ContentSearchRegular'` ==> give error : `query string is missing or invalid`.

I also tried using the legacy osssearchresults.aspx page. No more progress.

What's puzzling me is that the same test (`"it's working"`) works as expected on a local SP2013 environment..

How can I search for item with the `Title` equals to `it's working` ?

What did I missed ?

Comment: Try reindex this list. Gear>List Settings>Advanced Settings>Reindex List

Comment: @MarkoTica: I already tried this, several times, on the list and on the web itself. Moreover, the data in the index seems correct. Using Search query tool, I can see the title is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finaly was able to perform query against data with single quote.

I created a new managed property, where I check "Exact matching" option.

Querying against this managed property worked with my single quote.

Ex:

```
MyBrandNewManagedProp:"It's working"
```

As a side note, I contacted the Microsoft Support. The only response I got is that's "by design" and it won't be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I could search items with ' in title without any issues on my end. Below are my test results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You test isn't accurate. You are searching is equivalent to `(Title:it's) OR (working)` which is not correct. It may returns the result but also any other data that match one of the two predicate. I need to retrieve items that have exactly "It's working" in its title

Comment: I also tried Title:"it's working". Also get the search result.

Comment: Thanks. I start to think there's something broken in the platform. I never have issue like this. I guess I'll have to open a ticket. Thanks

Comment: You could try to test in different site collections.

Comment: I tried in two different tenants

Comment: The support wasn't able to help me (the classic "it' by design" to skip the problem). However, I was able to find a partial solution.